# Net Core 2 / Razor - theming(views, not css only)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for solution which would allow me to serve different templates depends on what is set in session (middleware will set it based on the domain).

What I al looking for is that when the theme is set up, when some view suppose to be rendered, mvc would render the view from particular theme.

How can I do that with net core 2,mvc and razor? It would be great if adding theme wouldn't require recompilation (e.g.  similar to Wordpress - upload zip file with all required files).

I really have no idea where to start...

I was trying to Google some solutions but I found only one which is outdated totally.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to customize the list of directories that Razor searches for views. By default, those are `Views\{controller}` and `Views\Shared`. You just need to make it so those are instead (or maybe as well as, to have fallback to a "base" theme if a particular theme chooses not to provide a view) `{theme}\Views\{controller}` and `{theme}\Views\Shared`, or something similar.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) doesn't provide much support here. All you get is:

> You can customize the default convention for how views are located within the app by using a custom [IViewLocationExpander](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander).

As the name implies, that's an interface that Razor uses to get a list of locations to search for views in. In other words, you'd simply need to create your own implementation and then inject that. Something like [`LanguageViewLocationExpander`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/LanguageViewLocationExpander.cs) should give you an idea of what you need to do, since the basic principle at play is the same. It's used for localization and provides the ability to have views nested under language specific-folders.

Comment: This methods works great and I have implmentmented